# How to split a column with multiple entries and numbers by removing the brackets and adding new rows?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, split

I have data for existing items in the range as follows:

| Type of Article | Article Name |
| --- | --- |
| T-Shirt | T-Shirt Black (99148137017000) T-Shirt Orange-Blue (99019009017000)T-Shirt Pink Green Gold (99019009017111) |
| Blouse | Blouse Black (99148134417000) Blouse Green (99555134417000) |
| Jeans | Jeans Blue (99258934417000) |

As you can see, for each type of article their are sometimes several articles with different item numbers in brackets (that are beginning with 99), which are in one cell.

However, I would like to split the article names with the corresponding number without brackets into two columns and at the same time add a new row with the transfer of the type of article. So that it looks like this:

| Type of Article | Article | Article Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T-Shirt | T-Shirt Black | 99148137017000 |
| T-Shirt | T-Shirt Orange-Blue | 99019009017000 |
| T-Shirt | T-Shirt Pink Green Gold | 99019009017111 |
| Blouse | Blouse Black | 99148134417000 |
| Blouse | Blouse Green | 99555134417000 |
| Jeans | Jeans Blue | 99258934417000 |

I have already searched for answers to similar questions and have already tried `tidyr::separate()` and `separate()`, but unfortunately without success.

Can you please suggest how can I perform this in **R**?

Thank you very much in advance.